# How to use Quill Text Editor as a component in Vue3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-component, text-editor, quill

1 - Installation NPM / Yarn

- npm install @vueup/vue-quill@latest --save *# OR* yarn add @vueup/vue-quill@latest

2 - Usage in component

```
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

export default {
  components: {
    QuillEditor
  }
}
<template>
    <QuillEditor v-model:content="form.description" content-type="html" theme="snow" toolbar="full" />
</template>
```

Am I doing this​​ right in component vue3 ?

Comment: it looks fine as per documentation https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/usage.html#in-single-file-component.

Try using Global Registration

Answer (score 0):

The way we solved this by only using the official package is:

```
<div
   id="text-editor"
   ref="textEditorEl"
   class="text-editor__editor"
/>
```

Then we use composition api, but im sure option api is the same concept:

Add a field for the quill editor `let textEditorEl = null`

Add a onMounted, in which you add a nextTick, to be sure the ref is ready.

Add a

```
    quillEditor = new Quill(textEditorEl.value || '#text-editor', {
                modules: {
                    toolbar: true,
                },
                theme: 'snow',
            });
```

Ofcourse this is just the basics, styling etc is custom for our application so cant help you with that. Good luck!